# How to find the superuser for a container in adls2

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake

I have a container created by someone and I'm using it load the data. In the manage access tab I see my user name and also $superuser(Owner) and $superuser(Owning Group) with different level of ACLs set.

How to find who is the superuser for that container? I tried Get Properties [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/datalakestoragegen2/path/getproperties) but still seeing the response as $superuser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`Az`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-3.8.0) powershell command to get `$superuser(Owner)`, it returns the `Object ID` of the `Owner`, which could be a user, group, service principal in Azure AD.

```
Connect-AzAccount
$storageAccount = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName <group-name> -AccountName <storage-account-name>
$ctx = $storageAccount.Context
$filesystemName = "<container-name>"
$filesystem = Get-AzDataLakeGen2Item -Context $ctx -FileSystem $filesystemName
$filesystem.Owner
```

[image]

If you want to get the details of the `Object ID`, you could use the [`AzureAD`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0-preview) command below.

```
Connect-AzureAD
Get-AzureADObjectByObjectId -ObjectIds $filesystem.Owner
```

[image]

**Update:**

Yes, you could use the azure cli command [`az storage blob directory access show`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ext/storage-preview/storage/blob/directory/access?view=azure-cli-latest#ext-storage-preview-az-storage-blob-directory-access-show), first you need to add the `storage-preview` extension.

```
az extension add -n storage-preview
az login
az storage blob directory access show -d '/' -c '<container-name>' --account-name '<account-name>'
```

[image]

It also returns the `Object ID` of the `$superuser(Owner)`, but in azure cli, there is no built-in command to get the directory object with `Object ID`, you can get the details about the object with [`az ad user show`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/user?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-user-show), [`az ad sp show`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/sp?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-sp-show), [`az ad group show`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/group?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-group-show), you need to know the type of the object previously.

If you don't know the type of the object, you can just use [`az rest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest#az-rest) to call [Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directoryobject-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to get the details.

```
az rest --method get --uri https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/<Object ID>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @JoyWang, is it possible to get the filesystem owner from Azure CLI or any other workaround as I don't have Windows OS

Comment: this is really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: For some reason, when I execute the powershell procedure specified the $filesystem.owner property is empty, as is Length, LastModified, Permissions, Owner & Group property. Any idea why?

Comment: @JoyWang, Why I am still getting `superuser`  and not the `objectid`?
`PS /home/tom> $ctx =  New-AzStorageContext teststorageact
PS /home/tom> $filesystem = Get-AzDataLakeGen2Item -Context $ctx -FileSystem 'testContainer'
PS /home/tom> $filesystem.Owner
PS /home/tom> $filesystem.owner`
$superuser 'This the output of the previous command $filesystem.owner